# How to find most frequnet words in a corpus in Pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, text-mining, countvectorizer

I have Pandas dataframe that looks like following.I have tokenized my text files and used `NLTK` `Countvectorizer` to convert into `pandas` dataframe. In addition, I have already removed stopwords and punctuation from my coupus. I am trying to find most frequent words in my corpus in `pandas` dataframe. In below dataframe,words such as "aaron" and "abandon" aprreared >10 times, thus those words should be in new dataframe.

*Note: I am new to python, and I am  not sure how to implement this. Provide explanation with code.*

**Subset of the dataframe**

I already already clean my corpus and my `dataframe` looks like following

```
{'aaaahhhs': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 0, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 1}, 'aahs': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 0, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 1}, 'aamir': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 0, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 1}, 'aardman': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 0, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 2}, 'aaron': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 4, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 14}, 'abandon': {990: 0, 991: 0, 992: 0, 993: 0, 994: 0, 995: 0, 996: 0, 997: 0, 998: 0, 999: 0, 1000: 16}}
```

[image]

Comment: According to your edit, you need `df[df.sum().nlargest(2).index]` 2 being the number of largest values you are looking for for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need top N words:

```
N = 2 
print (df.sum().nlargest(N).index)
Index(['aaron', 'abandon'], dtype='object')
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index[:N])
Index(['aaron', 'abandon'], dtype='object')
```

If need also counts in one column `DataFrame` or `Series` (remove `to_frame`):

```
N = 2
print (df.sum().nlargest(N).to_frame('count'))
         count
aaron       18
abandon     16
print (df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[:N].to_frame('count'))
         count
aaron       18
abandon     16
```

If need 2 column `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.sum().nlargest(N).rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='count'))
      word  count
0    aaron     18
1  abandon     16

print (df.sum()
         .sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[:N]
         .rename_axis('word')
         .reset_index(name='count'))
      word  count
0    aaron     18
1  abandon     16
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dftop2 = pd.DataFrame(df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2))
```

and you get:

```
         0
aaron   18
abandon 16
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting another way